# Возможно ли ускорить полный перебор?

Tags: алгоритм, многопоточность, map-reduce, apache-spark

Есть транспортная задача с промежуточными пунктами и ограничениями на пропускную способность. Кроме того, имеется транспортный парк. В задаче необходимо найти оптимальное решение по стоимости перевозки, но это решение будет зависеть не только от длины маршрута, но и от количества и типа выбранных транспортных средств.

Не вижу иного решения, кроме как перебирать возможные комбинации транспорта и решать для этой комбинации транспортную задачу, ибо целью стоит нахождение именно оптимального решения, квази-оптимальное не пойдет.

Поскольку при увеличении количества или же разнообразия задача становится нерешаемая за доступное время, стоит вопрос: а возможно ли как нибудь это дело ускорить ? Какие средства/методы можно здесь применить ? Возможно ли привязать сюда map reduce или apache spark ?

ps При решении возможно использование большого количества пк
pps За доступное время - предполагается, что можно считать и несколько дней, и недель

Comment: точное решение  NP-полных задач полным перебором означает перебор О(2**N) вариантов... Может подумаете о приближенных решениях?

Comment: @VasylKolomiets Приближенные решения - это не совсем то, что хотелось бы, ибо теоретически для решения такой задачи будет предложено использовать не 1 пк, а в общем-то сеть, теоретически, не маленькую. Ну и под доступным временем подразумевалась тоже не секунда/минута, пара недель тоже будет ничего =)

Comment: Написание максимально быстрого нативного кода - определенно вариант решения. Вряд ли что-то будет быстрее него ;-)

Comment: Нашел для себя Apache Ignite. Пока до конца не уверен, но по всей видимости, это то, что поможет мне осуществить распределенное вычисление. Может, кто в курсе этой штуки ?

Comment: @АлександрБерлускони распределённые вычисления можно реализовать и с мап-редьюсом из Hadoop'а, и с помощью Spark'а. нужно определить последовательность обработки исходных данных и части, которые можно распараллелить, а дальше - чистая реализация, используя API